# How to put a bar on top of a hat

Tags: stacking-symbols

I'm trying to type the conjugate of the fourier transform, so I want a bar over a hat. I only really know one way of doing this but these come out VERY scrambled:
`$\overline{hat{f}}$` or `$\bar{\hat{f}}$`.

Help?

Comment: Precisely for reasons like this, it is much better to use an asterisk for the conjugate.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Unfortunately, I am pretty stuck with this notation right now.

Comment: Which math font do you use? And, are you loading the `amsmath` package? With this package loaded, `$\bar{\hat{f}}$` should mlook alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `accents` package was designed for exactly the problem of stacking accents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
$\bar{\hat f}$
\end{document}
```

It redefines the way that accents are set up in regular LaTeX. This looks about right to me.

If you are using `unicode-math`, the OpenType maths fonts should be able to stack their accents well by default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{xits-math.otf}
\begin{document}
$\bar{\hat f}$
\end{document}
```

Well, it's not perfect…

Answer (score 1):

It may work to use something of the following form, which just stacks one symbol on top of another:

\stackrel{upper symbol}{lower symbol}

For the upper symbol, could you just use a rule?

Comment: This answer is somewhat incomplete, and would be better suited as a comment.